# Is this a whole-part design pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have to explain a pattern based on some text, but I'm not sure what the real name of this pattern is. According to this text it called "The Part" and its purpose is the generalization of the concept like that of a person physical and/or organizational

- Individual:

  - Internal: Employees, Shareholders
  - External: customers, suppliers, debtors,
    creditors, etc.

• Organization:

- Internal: Managers, departments, sections
- External: customers, suppliers, debtors, etc.

(Each classification can be subclassified)

[image: Diagram]

Is there a specific name for this pattern? Or if it doesn't have a name, is there any real life example I could use for reference?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The external and internal parts are supposed to be types of Person and Organization, to be honest this seems like inheritance but I don't quite know if that is the correct term.

Comment: Which are classes? Is `External` a class? Or is `Employee` a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book Analysis Patterns by Martin Fowler, in the chapter about [*Accountability* (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf), this pattern is called *Party: An abstraction of people and organizational units*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I dunno why the couldn't just give us the damn chapter or at least the correct name.